# Hiding table columns with javascript - dynamically adjust layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

As part of my responsive design, I'm trying to dynamically hide columns of a table if the viewport size shrinks past a certain point. I've tried to set
`.style.visibility = "collapse"` for all `<tr>` elements and `.style.opacity = "0"` for all `<td>` elements. I then have to hide the `background` of the table so that it doesn't show that the table width is still there while also increasing the `width` of the table (160%) so that the remaining columns fill the screen.

While this actually works on Chrome, Firefox, IE (including ie8!) and my mobile browsers, it seems like a ridiculous kludgy hack. Any other suggestions?

```
    var jmq = window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 610px)");
    jmq.addListener(jmqListener);

    function jmqListener(jmq){
        var colTitle = getElementsByClassName('col-title');
        var colName = getElementsByClassName('col-name');
        var colDate = getElementsByClassName('col-date');
        var colFb = getElementsByClassName('col-fb');
        var table = getElementsByClassName('default');

        if (jmq.matches || window.innerWidth < 611 ) {
            //Mobile
            ... resize controls
            // hide table columns
            if (colName !== null){
                for(var i=0,j=colName.length; i<j; i++){
                    colName[i].style.visibility = "collapse";
                    colName[i].style.opacity = "0";
                }
            }
            // HACK - increase table width and hide the background which would show the reserved table space
            if (table !== null){
                for(var i=0,j=table.length; i<j; i++){
                    table[i].style.width = "160%";
                    table[i].style.background = "transparent";
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            // Desktop
            ... restore control layout for desktop
            // restore table column(s)
            if (colName !== null){
                for(var i=0,j=colName.length; i<j; i++){
                    colName[i].style.visibility = "visible";
                    colName[i].style.opacity = "100";
                }
            }
            if (table !== null){
                for(var i=0,j=table.length; i<j; i++){
                    table[i].style.width = "100%";
                    table[i].style.background = "#C8C8C8";
                }
            }
        }    
    }

function getElementsByClassName(className) {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName) { 
        return document.getElementsByClassName(className); }
    else { 
        return document.querySelectorAll('.' + className); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Any reason you don't use media queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your for loop:

```
for(var i=0; i<colName.length; i++){
    colName[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Note your `j` variable is completely superfluous.

In the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) for `visibility` you will find:

> **collapse**
>   For table rows, columns, column groups, and row groups the row(s) or column(s) are hidden and the space they would have occupied is removed (as if display: none were applied to the column/row of the table). However, **the size of other rows and columns is still calculated as though the cells in the collapsed row(s) or column(s) are present.** This was designed for fast removal of a row/column from a table without having to recalculate widths and heights for every portion of the table.

*emphasis mine*

The solution above is essentially to use `display: none`

Comment: I tried `display:none` on the `<tr>` elements before I went into hiding the `<td>` elements. Not sure why I didn't try `display:none` on `<td>` before changing `opacity`. One oddity, it messes up the phone's calculation for `zoom` level so that the `viewport` doesn't exactly match the container. I have to zoom out so no scrolling is required. Something else to adjust. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using CSS3 Media Queries.

E.g.

```
@media all and (max-width: 700px) {
table, tr, td {
    display: none;
}
```

When the width of your devices view-port is less than or equal to 700px the above `display: none;` will be used to hide your table, tr, td, or what have you.

Comment: Media queries would probably work in this case. I need js for changing other properties. Changing properties with js isn't compatible with CSS since they work at a different level => js works on the element level and @media queries work at the CSS level. I will give it a try a bit later anyway and verify. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: +1 Yes, it works. I'm probably going to stick with the javascript, though since all the other viewport modifications need to be done there. Thanks!